# Line $A$ is $18$ inches, Line $B$ is $7.04$ inches and bend angle is $13^\circ$. If $A||C$, calculate height between Line $A$ and $C$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

In the diagram, Line $A$ is $18$ inches, Line $B$ is $7.04$ inches and bend angle is $13^\circ$. Considering Line $A$ and $C$ are parallel to each other, calculate the height between Line $A$ and $C$.

[image]

Comment: That acute angle is extremely obtuse looking.

Answer (score 0):

If angle AB is 13 degrees, then angle BC is 77 degrees.  Therefore, the line from A to C (the adjacent) divided by line B (the hypotneuse) would be the cosine of 77 degrees.

$\cos(77)\times7.04 = 1.584$ which is the length of the line from A to C.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Hope the picture is more helpful,if not, we can restore it.

Comment: Does not really matter if the formula to calculate the height between A & C is the same.